# RAD Server Delphi - using savetostream und loadfromstream does not work because of mutated vowels after Json conversion

Tags: json, delphi, firedac, delphi-10.4-sydney, fdmemtable

I try to exchange Data via RadServer IIS Package and Delphi Client with EMSEndpoint.
What I try looks simple to me but I can't get it done now.

In the Package there is a TFDConnection pointing to a MSSql Server. TFDQuery is connected with that Connection.
With this code I create the JSON Response (Serverside):

```
var lStream: TStringStream := TStringStream.create;

    FDQuery.SaveToStream(lStream,sfJSON);
    AResponse.Body.SetStream(lStream,'application/json' ,True);
```

with that code I try to load the Dataset into TFDMemtable (Clientside):

```
 lstrstream: TStringStream := TStringStream.create(EMSBackendEndpoint.Response.Content);
 aMemtable.LoadFromStream(lstrstream, sfJSON);
```

The Memtable says `[FireDac][Stan]-719 invalid JSON storage format`
How could that be? I know where the Problem is, there are äöü Symbols in my Stream, but when I load that from one Component to the other it should work, shouldn't it?
Any suggestions what I can try? What I have tryed so far:

- Loading JSON in Client over UTF8toUnicode. That let me load the Memtable but results in missing Letters like öäü
- Changing UTF8toUnicode on the Serverside and backwords on the Client side. That leads to not readable JSON for the Memtable
- Loading JSON into JSONString and Format it localy before loading into Memtable. That leads to not Readable JSON because also the Array and Object chars are quoted out.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Livesafer like everytime. If you write that down to a short Answer I would love to accept it.

Comment: answer posted now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is most commonly exchanged using UTF-8, but by default `TStringStream` *does not* use UTF-8 on Windows, only on Posix systems. Try using `TStringStream.Create(..., TEncoding.UTF8)` to force UTF-8.

This assumes that `FDQuery.SaveToStream()` saves using UTF-8, and `aMemtable.LoadFromStream()` loads using UTF-8, otherwise you will still have an encoding mismatch.